# Exclude items from results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to search a mongodb with python. I'd like to give the query a list of item ids in order to exclude them from the search results.

I tried with this query but I get no results:

```
flagged_articles = ["er12", "rt43"]
query = {

    "from": page*limit,
    "size": limit,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "range": {
                    "added" : {
                        "from" : "2013-04-11T00:00:00"
                    }
                }
          },
          "ids" : {
            "values" : flagged_articles
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be faster if you did this with a filter rather than a query. A filter doesn't do any score calculation and so has a lighter overhead.

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "range": {
                "added" : {
                    "from" : "2013-04-11T00:00:00"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "not" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "ids" : {
                        "values" : ["123", "456", "789"]
                    }
                },
                "_cache" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: The `not` filter is not cached by default (the other filters are usually cached). I've added a `_cache: true` parameter to show you have to cache the `not` filter if you think you will be using it on subsequent searches.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From the ES Docs here (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/), you should use the `bool` filter's/query's `must_not` to exclude results. Reworked example:

```
flagged_articles = ["er12", "rt43"]

query = {
    "from": page*limit,
    "size": limit,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "range": {
                    "added" : {
                        "from" : "2013-04-11T00:00:00"
                    }
                }
            },
            "must_not" : {
                "terms": {
                    "article.id" : flagged_articles
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Untested, but that should point you in the right direction, I think.

Edit: clarification, you can obviously use the `ids` filter where I've put the `terms` filter.